# Horizontal line without indenting

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, line, horizontal

This is the result I want to have (I want to obtain the result that most resembles this mathematical expression):

[image]

What I have tried is this:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
    01\: 1011 \: 0110\\
    11\: 0001 \: 1101\\
    \hline
    11\: 1011 \: 1111\\
    01\: 0001 \: 0100\\
    10\: 1010 \: 1011
\end{aligned}
\]
```

Result:

[image]

I don't know how to insert the text "bitwise OR", "bitwise AND" and also to reduce the spacing between the numbers.

PD: The font color doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usa a `tabular`, with `booktabs` and its prettier rules.

I chose to typeset four columns, so you can decide upon the spacing as you please; I find `\thinspace` better. You can use `\hspace{<length>}` as you please instead. Also `$\:$` would do, if you prefer that space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % right aligned math

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  R@{\thinspace}
  R@{\thinspace}
  R
  l
  @{}
}
01 & 1011 & 0110\\
11 & 0001 & 1101\\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r){1-3}
11 & 1011 & 1111 & bitwise OR \\
01 & 0001 & 0100 & bitwise AND \\
10 & 1010 & 1011 & bitwise XOR
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. The horizontal line goes a little bit outer the column on the right!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}c l}
    01& 1011 &  0110\\
    11& 0001 &  1101\\
    \cline{1-3}
    11& 1011 &  1111 && bitwise \textit{OR}\\
    01& 0001 &  0100 && bitwise \textit{AND} \\
    10& 1010 &  1011 && bitwise \textit{XOR}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

You alse can use the `alignedat` environment to have full control on the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, hhline}

\begin{document}

\[ \aboverulesep = -2.5ex\belowrulesep = -1ex\arrayrulecolor{SkyBlue}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
    & 01 & \: & 1011 & \: & 0110\\
    & 11 & \: & 0001 & \: & 1101\\
    \cmidrule[0.15ex]{1-6}
     & 11 & \: & 1011 & \: & 1111 &\qquad &\text{\color{SkyBlue}bitwise \emph{OR}} \\
     & 01 & \: & 0001 & \: & 0100 & & \text{\color{SkyBlue}bitwise \emph{AND}}\\
     & 10 & \: & 1010 & \: & 1011 & & \text{\color{SkyBlue}bitwise \emph{XOR}}
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course, someone needs to show how to do this with a `matrix` construct in TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \matrix (BINARY)
         [matrix of nodes,
          row sep=4pt,
          nodes={font=\sffamily,}]
  { 
    01  & 1011 & 0110 \\
    11  & 0001 & 1101 \\
    %% -----------------
    11  & 1011 & 1111 \\%% bitwise OR  
    01  & 0001 & 0100 \\%% bitwise AND 
    10  & 1010 & 1011 \\%% bitwise XOR 
  };

  \draw ($(BINARY-2-1.south west)!0.5!(BINARY-3-1.north west)$) -- 
        ($(BINARY-2-3.south east)!0.5!(BINARY-3-3.north east)$);

  \node[anchor=west,blue] at (BINARY-3-3.east) {bitwise OR};
  \node[anchor=west,blue] at (BINARY-4-3.east) {bitwise AND};
  \node[anchor=west,blue] at (BINARY-5-3.east) {bitwise XOR};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For the comments on last three rows you could, alternatively, use a `\foreach` loop as follows:

```
\foreach \myn/\myop in {3/OR,4/AND,5/XOR}
  {
    \node[anchor=west,blue] at (BINARY-\myn-3.east) {bitwise \myop};    
  }
```